# Excel "INDIRECT" function with parameter from "CONCATENATE"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am using an INDIRECT function to get value of a cell (B4) for many sheets in my workbook. 
At the moment I have to hard code the name of the sheets like this

```
=INDIRECT("WCNEXP!$B$4")
```

Ideally I would like to find a way to compile the name "WCNEXP" with the help of the CONCATENATE formula, like this

```
=INDIRECT("CONCATENATE(B18,C18)!$B$4")
```

but it does not work for some reason.

Is there another way to get the name compiled from 2 cells and use the INDIRECT Formula ?

[Photo of the workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD0Cd.png)

Comment: `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B18,C18, "!$B$4"))` ? i.e. not the TEXT "Concatenate" (since you put it inside the double quotes).

Comment: Agree with FXD - an alternate solution would be to cut `CONCATENATE` all together: `=INDIRECT(B18&C18&"!$B$4")`

Comment: FXD that is genius, thanks a million!

Comment: And what about the following case =IFERROR(COUNTA(WALCBU!$A$3:$A$115),"") . =COUNTA(CONCATENATE(B18,C18, "$A$3:$A$111") does not seem to work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost good.
the quotes must be placed after the concatenate function, and with the use of "&" to join them.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B18,C18)&"!$B$4")
```

Comment: And what about in the following case =IFERROR(COUNTA(WALCBU!$A$3:$A$115),"") . =COUNTA(CONCATENATE(B18,C18)& "$A$3:$A$111") does not seem to work though. ANy ideas?

Comment: The "counta" function only counts the number of occurancies of a value. 
So, those two formulas only work for counting elements but do not give you the value. 
If i have 3 values (text or number) in the A3:A111 area, then =COUNTA(CONCATENATE(B18,C18)& "$A$3:$A$111") will give me the number 3. 
It's the same for the other formula, but it only returns "" if the counta function delivers an error.