# Change sheet name in a Transpose formula dynamically in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my workbook, I have a summary sheet showing data from multiple customers and then one sheet per customer with all the details. In the summary sheet, Column A contains the names of the sheet for each customer. At the moment I have to hard code the name of the sheets like this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SheetName!$C$4:$C$13)
```

How can I update the sheet name dynamically based on the values on column A?

PS: I'm using the transpose formula because in the individual sheets the values I want to bring to the summary sheet are all in a column but in the summary sheet I need them in a row.

I looked [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55196036/excel-indirect-function-with-parameter-from-concatenate), but does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are working in google sheets, you can use indirect() function. Here is the code that will work for you.

For getting sheet name automatically from column A cell:

```
=TRANSPOSE(indirect(A1&"!$B$1:$C$13"))
```

you can drag the same formula to get all the names further in column A.

Comment: Angela, if you find it useful, please up-vote my solution by clicking up arrow on my answer box's upper left side.